# Spring Boot x Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot

O Spring Boot é a mesma coisa que o Spring MVC?

Na prática não se usa mais Spring MVC (ou, deveria não utilizar) e apenas o Spring Boot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Spring MVC** é uma estrutura [MVC](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-padrao-mvc/29308) completa baseada em `HTTP` gerenciada pelo [Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) e baseada em Servlets. Seria equivalente ao `JSF` na pilha `JavaEE`. Os elementos mais populares nele são classes com o `@Controller` qual você implementa métodos que você pode acessar usando diferentes solicitações HTTP. Possui um equivalente `@RestController` a implementar APIs baseadas em `REST`.
- **Spring boot** é um utilitário para configurar aplicações rapidamente, oferecendo uma configuração "fora da caixa" para criar aplicativos com `Spring`. Como você pode saber, a Spring integra uma ampla gama de módulos diferentes em seu [portifólio](https://spring.io/projects) , como `spring-core` , `spring-data` , `spring-web` e assim por diante. Com esta ferramenta, você pode utilizar e configurar de forma rápida vários módulos de acordo com sua necessidade

Então, podemos dizer que

> [Spring MVC](http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-spring-mvc-criando-aplicacoes-web-em-java/31521) é uma estrutura para ser usada em aplicativos da Web

e

> [Spring boot](https://domineospring.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/comecando-com-a-magia-do-spring-boot/) é um inicializador de projetos prontos para produção

Outra observação importante é que `Spring Boot` pode usar `Spring MVC`.
Para isto basta importar o jar do `Spring-boot-starter-web`, ele já é autoconfigurado e pronto para usar. Quando você faz isto, basicamente, você está falando sobre usar o Spring Boot ou configurar manualmente o Spring Application. Spring boot é apenas ferramenta de autoconfiguração, Spring mvc é uma estrutura da web

Comment: Para aprender spring boot, preciso primeiro aprender spring mvc?

Comment: Não necessariamente, na verdade, eu indicaria você a estudar o `spring-boot`, pois você vai conseguir aprender os outros modulos do spring parte a parte e conforme a necessidade, e naturalmente você vai chegar ao spring-mvc, [neste link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/desenvolvendo-uma-aplicacao-web-com-spring-boot-e-spring-mvc/34122)  tem um artigo mostrando o desenvolvimento com spring-boot e spring-mvc.

Answer (score 0):

O Spring MVC e o Spring Boot tem propósitos diferentes, um é para renderizar páginas html e trabalhar com o protocolo http dentro do código(este seria o Spring MVC). E o outro o Spring boot é um projeto para feito pela pivotal para que se consiga contruir rapidamente aplicações java para microservicos, portanto se usa dentro do Spring boot o Spring MVC. Pode ser um pouco confuso já que o Spring Boot tem um servidor http dentro, e quando alguém fala em http pode ser que esteja referenciando o Spring Boot, porém que literalmente auxilia a executar operações http dentro do código java é o Spring MVC.

OBS: Só cuidado que o Spring MVC nao tem a parte do observer descrita no padrão, portanto não é o padrão completo. :D